# Merging Tables - EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have 12 sheets ( one for each month of the year ) with employes name and salary. Is there a way to merge these sheet, sort them by name then month and calculate their total salary earnings that years ? I tried using pivot tables and Consolidate and that did not work. Any Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before with easily over 100 sheets (1 per contractor company), I've acheieved the merged sheet by using Extend Office. It adds a tonne of useful functionality to your Excel with their software I only needed it a handful of times so the 30 day trial was sufficient

[Check it Out!](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1184-excel-merge-multiple-worksheets-into-one.html)